# prettier single quote error and do not define components during render

Tags: react-native, prettier

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZtNz.png)

prettier starts giving single quote error and also delete 'cr' error. the application runs fine for App.tsx if i only use single quote but the navigation components are not visible and shows do not define components during render.

to solve this i tried the following:

1. to remove delete 'cr' and single quote error

rules: {
'prettier/prettier': 0,
}

2. "prettier/prettier": ["error", { "singleQuote": true }]

To solve do not define component during render error i use call back function but this error pops up: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yodb.png)(images attached):